# Best way to check user's permission by id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization

In Rails3 application i have a number of models with user_id - this way i'm saying: it was created by some user.

Like:

```
current_user.id #=> 1
@item.user_id #=> 1
# this item created by user with id 1
```

And i want to restrict current_user's acess to items which was not created by him/her.

Something like:

```
if @item.user_id == current_user.id
  #everything is fine
else
  #redirect somwhere with flash "You don't have an access here"
end
```

What is the best way for this, because i have multiple number of models (and controllers to show/edit/destroy) with such a user_id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)!

With it you will be able to define permissions declaratively, like this:

```
can :read, Project, :user_id => user.id
```

And later enforce this rule:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :read, @project
end
```

`authorize!` will raise an exception, but you can check in a more peaceful manner:

```
<%= link_to 'Link to a project', @project if can? :read, @project %>
```

You can intercept authorization errors and handle them in one place:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this, is to use Active Record's `has_many`.

Namely, in a controller, whenever you load the `Item`, you just say

```
@item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])
```

This way you don't have to do any work to check.